Why does Java WeakReference not get enqueued if the WeakReference itself is not reachable anymore by application code?
I am debugging a weird issue with Java WeakReferences. In some circumstances, it seems that they do not get added to the ReferenceQueue.
I have the following code:
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class Test {
    private static final ReferenceQueue<Object> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    private static final List<WeakReference<Object>> references = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private static void add(Object object) {
        var reference = new WeakReference(object, queue);
        references.add(reference);
        System.out.println("Created reference! :)");
    }

    private static void clean() {
        while (true) {
            var ref = queue.poll();
            if (ref == null)
                return;

            System.out.println("Cleaning up reference! :)");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean clearImmediately = args[0].equals("true");

        add(new Object());
        if (clearImmediately) {
            references.clear();
        }

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        if (!clearImmediately) {
            references.clear();
        }

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        clean();
    }
}


If I run it with java test.java false, I get:
Created reference! :)
Cleaning up reference! :)

Now if I run it with java test.java true, I get:
Created reference! :)

The WeakReference could be a subclass holding to some external resource that needs cleanup... Why does the JVM not enqueue it? Thanks.

System.gc does not guarantee that it actually causes a garbage collection.

I want to think that this because, in your second case, the WeakReference itself becomes unreachable and gets garbage collected. There's never a chance to add it  (nor its referent) to the ReferenceQueue (if it gets finalized first?).

I have to admit I don't find that explanation plausible; I'd expect the constructor for the WeakReference to cause that reference.

@LouisWasserman what do you mean with “to cause that reference”?

To preserve a strong reference to the WeakReference until it can be processed by the ReferenceQueue.  Thinking back through the uses of WeakReference I've seen, I don't think any of them ever bothered with keeping their own strong reference to the WeakReference through the cleanup phase.

@LouisWasserman of course, there is a strong reference to the WeakReference during the constructor invocation, but every constructor invocation ends at some point. After that, it’s the caller’s responsibility to keep that reference. The crucial point is that there must be a strong reference to the WeakReference during the garbage collection run that is supposed to enqueue the reference. After the reference has been enqueued (I’m not sure if you mean that by “cleanup phase”), there is no need to maintain a strong reference to the WeakReference anymore.

Thanks for the comments and for the duplicate question marking. Indeed, I completely missed that the answer was in the documentation of java.lang.ref. (Didn't think of reading that)...

I suppose that not enqueuing the WeakReference itself if it gets collected can make sense: in the context of WeakHashMap, once the entry was removed from the map, there is no need to have it go through the reference queue.
I suppose that you need to be extra careful, and manually keep the references alive using for example IdentityHashMap, if you really need it.

@bploumhans yes, that’s the way it works with WeakHashMap and also with Cleaner. When the cleanup action is triggered explicitly, there is no need to go through the queue anymore and the garbage collection becomes more efficient. It’s also the natural way from the garbage collector implementation’s point of view: special actions are only necessary when the garbage collector encountered a reference object during the traversal. The unreachable objects are never touched.
